# ReOpening a mantis issue using MantisConnect

Tags: c#, .net, mantis

I'm trying to reopen resolved or closed Mantis issues using  MantisConnect
I have thusfar succeeded in changing the status of non resolved/closed issues but when the issue is one of these two, i keep getting the following Exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException
```

with the message:

> There is a problem with the XML that was received from the network. 
>       See inner exception for more details.

with inner Exception:

```
System.Xml.XmlException
```

With the message:

> The encoding in the declaration 'ISO-8859-1' does not match the encoding of the document 'utf-8'.

I'm using the update command to do the update described here: https://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl

got my mantisconnect code from github here:
https://github.com/mantishub/MantisDotNetClient

The funny thing is that the changes to other states and even to the resolved and closed state work, the Exception is only throws when the issue is already resolved or closed
I could not find any other commands in mantisconnect to reopen an issue, anyone have an idea.

Edit:
Mantis issue I was talking about in my comment The ticket: https://mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=16579

Comment: Do you have anything in the server logs? Sounds like an error is being triggered on the server side, perhaps due to lack of permissions to reopen the issue

Comment: Due to the awesome safety measures from our IT team I, unfortunatly, don't have acces to those logs at this time. I'm hoping of changing that soon. I have come across a mantisConnect bugtracker issue a day or two ago which I believe talks about this issue. I will try to post is soon. In the meantime I do believe it is a error on my part (the way i'm opening the ticket) since i had the same error when trying to upload an attachment with mantisconnect that had a fileName that already existed in the mantis issue

Comment: @RobertMunteanu I used Charles to monitor the trafic and found the following responce: acces denied, issue is readonly. I can however reopen the issue in mantis itself. This corresponds with the [issue](https://wiki.mantisbt.org/bugs/view.php?id=16579) i found

Comment: Ah, OK . So it's definitely a bug we need to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a bug in the mantis API I solved this problem by navigating the website using WebRequests and the bulk UP_STATUS feature from mantis. It's dirty but it works.

```
class MantisWebRequest
{
    public string Password { private get; set; }
    public string Username { private get; set; }

    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }
    public StreamReader Reader { get; private set; }
    public Stream DataStream { get; private set; }
    public WebResponse Response { get; private set; }
    public HttpWebRequest Request { get; private set; }
    public string Page { get; private set; }
    public MantisWebRequest(string username, string password)
    {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }

    public void Connect(string cookieName = null)
    {
        string loginurl = "http://mantispageurl/login.php";
        // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
        Request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(loginurl);
        // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
        Request.Method = "POST";
        Request.KeepAlive = true;

        if (cookieName != null)
            CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie(cookieName, Username, "/", new Uri(loginurl).Host));
        Request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;

        // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.  Modify this line accordingly
        string postData = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}&secure_session=on", Username, Password);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        DataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        DataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        DataStream.Close();
        // Get the response.
        Response = Request.GetResponse();
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        DataStream = Response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        Reader = new StreamReader(DataStream);
        // Read the content.
        Page = Reader.ReadToEnd();

        // Clean up the streams.
        Reader.Close();
        DataStream.Close();
        Response.Close();


    }

    private void POST(string url, string postData)
    {
        Request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        Request.Method = "POST";
        Request.KeepAlive = true;
        Request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        DataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        DataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        DataStream.Close();
        Response = Request.GetResponse();
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        DataStream = Response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        Reader = new StreamReader(DataStream);
        // Read the content.
        Page = Reader.ReadToEnd();

        // Clean up the streams.
        Reader.Close();
        DataStream.Close();
        Response.Close();
    }

    private void POST(string url, string postData, string tokenName)
    {
        string token = GetToken(tokenName);

        Request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        Request.Method = "POST";
        Request.KeepAlive = true;
        Request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;

        postData = string.Format("{0}={1}&{2}", tokenName, token, postData);

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
        Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
        Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        // Get the request stream.
        DataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
        // Write the data to the request stream.
        DataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        // Close the Stream object.
        DataStream.Close();
        Response = Request.GetResponse();
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        DataStream = Response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        Reader = new StreamReader(DataStream);
        // Read the content.
        Page = Reader.ReadToEnd();

        // Clean up the streams.
        Reader.Close();
        DataStream.Close();
        Response.Close();
    }

    private void GET(string url)
    {


        Request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        Request.Method = "GET";
        Request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;

        Response = Request.GetResponse();
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        DataStream = Response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        Reader = new StreamReader(DataStream);
        // Read the content.
        Page = Reader.ReadToEnd();

        // Clean up the streams.
        Reader.Close();
        DataStream.Close();
        Response.Close();

    }

    private string GetToken(string tokenName)
    {
        int tokenIndex = Page.IndexOf(tokenName);
        int endindex = tokenIndex + Page.Substring(tokenIndex).IndexOf(">", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        int startindex = Page.Substring(0, tokenIndex).LastIndexOf("<", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        string input = Page.Substring(startindex, endindex - startindex + 1);

        string valuestring = "value=\"";
        int tokenIndex2 = input.IndexOf(valuestring, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        int endindex2 = tokenIndex2 + valuestring.Length + input.Substring(tokenIndex2 + valuestring.Length).IndexOf("\"", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        int startindex2 = tokenIndex2 + valuestring.Length;
        string output = input.Substring(startindex2, endindex2 - startindex2);

        return output;
    }

    public void UpdateStatus(int[] issueIds, int statusId)
    {
        string tokenName = "bug_actiongroup_UP_STATUS_token";
        string formUrl = GetUpdateStatusUrl(issueIds);
        string formPostDataUrl = "http://mantispageurl/bug_actiongroup.php";
        string formPostData = GetUpdateStatusPostData(issueIds, statusId);

        GET(formUrl);
        POST(formPostDataUrl, formPostData, tokenName);
    }

    private string GetUpdateStatusUrl(int[] issueIds)
    {
        string postData = "?";
        foreach (var issueId in issueIds)
        {
            postData = string.Format("{0}&bug_arr%5B%5D={1}", postData, issueId);
        }
        postData = String.Format("{0}&action=UP_STATUS", postData);

        return "http://mantispageurl/bug_actiongroup_page.php" + postData;
    }

    private string GetUpdateStatusPostData(int[] issueIds, int statusId)
    {
        string postData = "action=UP_STATUS";
        foreach (var issueId in issueIds)
        {
            postData = string.Format("{0}&bug_arr%5B%5D={1}", postData, issueId);
        }
        postData = String.Format("{0}&status={1}&bugnote_text=", postData, statusId);

        return postData;

    }
```